# Cree una aplicacion en java y jpa conectandome a php admin y al hacer un select de los datos me da el si

Tags: java, mysql

[image: es un mensaje de advertencia(joptionpane) al hacer un select a la tabla pd:estoy usando persistencias... la base de datos se conecta correctamente!!]

cree una app de escritorio con java jpa, me conecto con la base de datos en php admin correctamente,
al momento de hacer un select a los registros me muestra el siguiente error

Comment: Claramente, tu tabla ingreso no tiene una columna id_producto.

Comment: Te "da el si"? por favor revisa [ask], recuerda agregar detalles a tu pregunta que ayuden a la comunidad a encontrar el problema rápidamente por ejemplo tu código y como es la estructira de tu tabla,saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El error con código 1054:

> SintaxErrorException: Unknown column "id_producto" in "field list"
> Error Code: 1054

indica  que no existe un campo "`id_producto`", en la tabla `ingreso` al realizar la consulta:

```
SELECT id_producto, categoría, nombre, valor_unitario FROM ingreso
```